# Current page url in PHP

Tags: php, url

I've this url: 
http://localhost/alignment/?page_id=52&q=2
I want to get the portion: ?page_id=52 , how can I do that?

Comment: Using google is the best option in this case.

Comment: do you need the string `?page_id=52` or do you want a variable `$page_id = 52`? if it's the last, just do `$page_id = $_GET['page_id'];`...

Answer (score 7):

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

or

```
$url = "http://localhost/alignment/?page_id=52&q=2";
$bits = explode("?", $url);
$querystring = $bits[1]; // this is what you want
```

but the first one will be much more reliable and is easier. :)

**EDIT**

if you meant that you just wanted that one variable use:

`$_GET['page_id']`

Comment: Won't that return `page_id=52&q=2`?

Comment: oh yeah... well read you there. :p then the answer is $_GET['page_id']

Answer (score 2):

This is called a query string. The main portion of the query string is separated by the rest of the URL with a `?`. Each argument in the query string is separated by a `&`.

PHP:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

If you want to get the individual pieces, use:

```
$_GET['page_id']; //etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the whole query string with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, but you would have to parse out page_id part.  If you insist on doing things manually the function [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) may come in handy.

A better choice would be to just use the predefined $_GET global variable.  `$_GET['page_id']` would give you value 52.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it as a string, use `parse_url`. Documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). Get the `query` value of it. or if its current request use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo parse_url($url,PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the url to string and then explode() it,
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php, using the ? as a delimiter